# c# WebBrowser not showing info inside

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

(First of all, sorry for my English)
Well, I have a problem in one client where the message I try to show doesn't appear in the component showing the component empty, this only happends in one client for about 1000. 
It started to fail since yesterday, client has Windows 7, I don't know his IE version

In this case, the only I'm doing with newValue is to introduce some words bold.

I can't reproduce this error on my machine, so anyone knows any reason (Windows Update, IE version, text inside,...) that could make it to fail or to show it blank??

WebBroser is inside a Form, I use it like MessageBox, but with this I can print colors or what else I figure in the message.

```
private void SetWebBrowserText(string newValue)
{
        try
        {
            if (this.webBrowser1.Document == null)
                this.webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue))
                newValue = String.Concat("<div><font color=\"#000000\" size=\"2\" face=\"verdana\">", newValue.Replace("\n", "<br>"), "</font></div>");

            webBrowser1.Document.Write(newValue);
        }
        catch { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vb.net:

```
Public Sub ShowMessage(ByVal htmlmsg As String)
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("")
    Do While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
    Loop
    WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml = htmlmsg
End Sub
```

C#:

```
   public void ShowMessage(string htmlmsg)
   {
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("");
    while (WebBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
        Application.DoEvents();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
    WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml = htmlmsg;
   }
```

Example:

```
ShowMessage("<h1>Msg</h1> <h2 style='color:Red'>red msg</h2>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally we found the solution by reinstall entirelly system from a clear installation, it seems framework  was corrupted or system registry of it.